# Не получается создать ProgressBar в Delphi.

Tags: delphi

Создаю ProgressBar в Delphi. Запускаю программу и вылетает ошибка. Вот [скриншот:](http://files.mail.ru/0PEZBS)

Answer (score 1):

Причем тут `ProgressBar`? Его класс лежит в модуле `ComCtrls.dcu`.

```
Unit ExtDlgs was compiled with a different version of Buttons. TSpeedButton
```

Эта ошибка говорит о том что проблемы в модуле `ExtDlgs.dcu`. Он скомпилен с использованием  класса `TSpeedButton` который отличается от того, что лежит в модуле `Buttons.dcu`. Вероятнее всего в IDE были установлены несовместимые с Delphi7 компоненты. Удали из проекта `ExtDlgs`, и те компоненты, которые с ним связаны.

Answer (score 0):

Если прогрессбар стандартный, то нужен модуль **ComCtrls**. Может, тогда компилятор его найти не может. Или модуль был подключен Вами самостоятельно (у меня, обычно, из-за этого была подобная проблема). Советую тупо бросить компонент на форму и, сразу же компилировать, по идее, так должно сработать.

Comment: Он стандартный. При запуске происходит ошибка, и указывает на ComCtrls.

Comment: Я тоже думал, что не может найти, но я уже сам его искал - нашёл. Скорее всего сам компилятор бракованный, лучше другой установлю, у меня есть другой.

Comment: Бракованный компилятор... Спасибо, посмеялся.